# Web Scraping URL issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the information for each business related to US crop farms and $5,000,000 in annual revenues or greater. The problem is that when I change options in the search parameters it doesn't change the URL...so I'm not sure how to go about a project like this...any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the website I'm trying to scrape: http://listings.findthecompany.com/d/a/Crop-Farms

Comment: Include any code or snippets showing what you have tried. This will allow people answering to understand where you may be going wrong in your approach and offer better help to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you capture the network, you can see that the webpage makes a call when you hit search.

http://listings.findthecompany.com/ajax_search?_len=20&page=0&app_id=1662&_sortfld=sales_volume_us&_sortdir=DESC&_fil%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=sic_1_4digit&_fil%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=%3D&_fil%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=0191&_fil%5B1%5D%5Bfield%5D=_sphinx_universal_search&_fil%5B1%5D%5Boperator%5D=LIKE&_fil%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Apple&_fil%5B1%5D%5Bignore%5D=false&_tpl=srp&head%5B%5D=company_name&head%5B%5D=_GC_address&head%5B%5D=total_employees&head%5B%5D=employees_here&head%5B%5D=sales_volume_us&head%5B%5D=year_started&head%5B%5D=citystate&head%5B%5D=localeze_classification&head%5B%5D=id&head%5B%5D=_encoded_title&dir_field_1=207944

You can actually check different parameters and get all the data you need.
I used 'Apple' as a search term, which is passed as a paramter.